# Firebase table with list

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an app where I store some data like :

- date(timestamp)
- pick-up date(string)
- delivery date(string)

The flow of my app is :

Login Activity - I use the FirebaseAuth to signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
Register Activity - I use the FirebaseAuth to createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
Let's call these info date, pickup, delivery UserInfo, ok?

Then when trying to add UserInfo I'm adding like this :

```
db.collection("users").document("myEmail").set(hasMapOf(...))
```

Structure of firebase db

```
MyDatabase-2d455
Users -
    idOfUser1
    idOfUser2
    idOfUser3 -
                date: "10/10/2019"
                pickup: "13:21"
                delivery : "15:21"
```

The output that I'd have to get is an user can only add this "pickup" and "delivery" once per day, so I don't know if this can change the database.. I mean, if today 17 Dec user set the pickup and delivery when I get this info from the app I should get that on 17 Dec the pickup was at X time and delivery at X time. So for 17 Dec can only be set one value, even if the user is updating these values every-time.

So what would be the best design for the data base in this case? If then I want to filter by month for instance and check how many days user have picked up and delivered a day?

### Sample example

User register to the app with email and password
User can login to the app with email and password
Then if the day of today is 17th of December then I want to user add the delivery and pickup address hours in that day (17th of December) so then from the app then I can filter by "December" and get all the days he inputs some data in these days.
But I'm thinking that maybe I can get all the records and then filter in the app, but if there's a simple way to do it from firebase I'd prefer to do so from there.

Comment: Which database are you using, the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore?

Comment: Cloud Firestore

Comment: In that case, please don't tag with `1firebase-realtime-database` in the future. The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases, and adding irrelevant tags just creates confusion.

Comment: Also: did you try anything already? Your use-case seems reasonable, but I'm having a hard time parsing what your problem is. Seeing the code that you already tried and didn't work will probably make that clearer.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also respond with @.

Answer (score 1):

> a user can only add this "pickup" and "delivery" once per day

If you want something to be unique in the database, use that as the key/ID in the database. Since you want the user to be only able to set one value per day, use the UID and the date as the key.

E.g. if your UID is `StuartDTO` and today is December 17, 2021, your key would be:

```
"StuartDTO_20211217"
```

This could either be the document ID, or a field inside an existing document; in both cases the value is guaranteed to be unique within its context.

So if the same user ever tries to set a different value for `"StuartDTO_20211217"`, they will end up overwriting the existing value. If that something you also want to disallow, you can reject updates in security rules.

Comment: But then how can I organise the user + email + list of StuartDTO_dateX? I mean, if in the future I want to have in the app a list of everything from the user form where I could get this query? And then, in case I want to filter per month? Like, return me all the days from decemeber, then I want a list of "pickup" and "delivery" for every date introduced.

Comment: That's a different requirement from what you shared before, but the logic is the same: if you want something to be unique in the database, use that as the key/ID in the database. If you want multiple combinations to be unique, you may end up with additional collections; one to ensure uniqueness for each combination.

Comment: Then how can be named my collections? And my documents? If I want to list all and then filter by month?

Comment: But how can I filter per month? I mean, now I have my documents as you proposed : "email_time" but then how can I get just the December ones for that specific email?
For instance now what I have as a document id is : "frank@profirebase.com_2021-12-21"

Comment: You'll query the same as before, on the field(s) in each document. Using the values in the document ID to ensure their uniqueness is not related to how you query for them.

Comment: I think I'm miss-explaining myself, the thing is I have a list of "frank@profirebase.com_2021-12-21", "frank@profirebase.com_2021-12-20", "frank@profirebase.com_2021-12-19", etc... how do I get only the ones that are from december?

Comment: There is no way to do a query on the postfix (end) of a list of keys like that. Hence: you will need to query on the fields in the documents, and use the keys to guarantee uniqueness.